# Saving web response to file

Tags: python, bash, curl

I have a GET Request like this

```
GET /index.php?id=3000 HTTP/1.1
Host: mywebsite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
```

Response

```
{"id":"3000","login":"aaaaa","first_name":"gggggg","name":"aaaa","email":"aaaaaa@gmail.com","phone":"000000
```

I want to download all Response to a single text file from ID 1 to 3000

I tired a simple bash script like this

```
xargs --max-args=10 -i wget http://mywebsite.com/index.php?id={} < id.txt
```

id.txt file contain id number from 1 to 3000

I couldn't make all response write to 1 file , the script create write each repose to separate file .

Comment: managed to do it   by adding -qO- > save_output.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
xargs -n 1 -i wget http://mywebsite.com/index.php?id={} -O - < id.txt > result.txt
```

if you don't want to create id.txt, you could also do

```
( for n in {1..3000} ; do wget http://mywebsite.com/index.php?id=$n -O - ; done ) > result.txt
```

Comment: yes that work too , instead giving all number in a file (id.txt) from 1 to 3000  , can u make one line without the id.txt file

to automatically check 1 to 3000 without id.txt file  and save all response to result.txt

Comment: Pls see my adapted answer.

You can use a bash for loop and `(` `)` to group stdout allowing you to redirect into one file